# R match one long format dataframe to another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, dplyr

I have two data frames, one for matching and another one is data. the one for matching is a long format.

```
  #long format df:

    Person  variable    type    value
1   claire  1   T   0.7396
2   murry   1   C   1.517824
3   kidson  1   T   1.686622
4   kai 1   T   1.4884
5   migu    1   A   1.2769
6   poka    1   G   1.5129
7   nomi    1   C   0.49
8   claire  2   TC  0.86
9   murry   2   CT  1.232
10  kidson  2   CT  1.2987
11  kai 2   CT  1.22
12  migu    2   GA  1.13
13  poka    2   GT  1.23
14  nomi    2   TC  0.7
15  claire  3   C   1
16  murry   3   T   1
17  kidson  3   C   1
18  kai 3   C   1
19  migu    3   G   1
20  poka    3   T   1
21  nomi    3   T   1

lfdf = structure(list(Person = c("claire", "murry", "kidson", "kai", 
"migu", "poka", "nomi", "claire", "murry", "kidson", "kai", "migu", 
"poka", "nomi", "claire", "murry", "kidson", "kai", "migu", "poka", 
"nomi"), variable = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), type = c("T", "C", 
"T", "T", "A", "G", "C", "TC", "CT", "CT", "CT", "GA", "GT", 
"TC", "C", "T", "C", "C", "G", "T", "T"), value = c(0.7396, 1.517824, 
1.686622, 1.4884, 1.2769, 1.5129, 0.49, 0.86, 1.232, 1.2987, 
1.22, 1.13, 1.23, 0.7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("Person", 
"variable", "type", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
21L))

#df:
Person  SB001   SB002   SB003   SB004
1   claire  C   T   T   TC
2   murry   T   T   T   T
3   kidson  CT  CT  T   T
4   kai C   T   CT  CT
5   migu    G   G   G   GA
6   poka    GT  G   T   T
7   nomi    TC  TC  T   TC

df <- structure(list(Person = c("claire", "murry", "kidson", "kai", 
"migu", "poka", "nomi"), SB001 = c("C", "T", "CT", "C", "G", 
"GT", "TC"), SB002 = c("T", "T", "CT", "T", "G", "G", "TC"), 
SB003 = c("T", "T", "T", "CT", "G", "T", "T"), SB004 = c("TC", 
"T", "T", "CT", "GA", "T", "TC")), .Names = c("Person", "SB001", 
"SB002", "SB003", "SB004"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
7L))

desired output:
    Person  SB001   SB002   SB003   SB004
1   claire  1   0.7396  0.7396  0.86
2   murry   1   1   1   1
3   kidson  1.2987  1.2987  1.686622    1.686622
4   kai 1   1.4884  1.22    1.22
5   migu    1   1   1   1.13
6   poka    1.23    1.5129  1   1
7   nomi    0.7 0.7 1   0.7
```

I would like to match the type into value in another dataframe, but after I turn it into the long format dataframe, I have not idea how to match it to the desired output.

Thank you for your help.
Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this using `melt` and `dcast` from `reshape2` package as follows,

**NOTE** I changed the name `value` from `lfdf` to `value1` because it was overlapping with `value` name given by `melt`

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(merge(melt(df, id.vars = 'Person'), lfdf, by.x = c('value', 'Person'), 
                   by.y = c('type', 'Person')), Person ~ variable.x, value.var = 'value1') 

#  Person  SB001  SB002    SB003    SB004
#1 claire 1.0000 0.7396 0.739600 0.860000
#2    kai 1.0000 1.4884 1.220000 1.220000
#3 kidson 1.2987 1.2987 1.686622 1.686622
#4   migu 1.0000 1.0000 1.000000 1.130000
#5  murry 1.0000 1.0000 1.000000 1.000000
#6   nomi 0.7000 0.7000 1.000000 0.700000
#7   poka 1.2300 1.5129 1.000000 1.000000
```

Comment: thanks, but if the long format is in wide format, what is the solution? becoz previously I think turn it into long format is easier to do

Comment: but now i think keep both wide format is easier to do? would you mind tell me how to do if both of the df are in wide format?

Comment: I think merging long format data frames is easier...less variables in long format

Comment: you are correct but now i m thinking if the data frame has many many columns then when it transforms to the long format, it would be taking time to merge, will it ?

Comment: Well yes, but this is true every time you scale up. Do some tests yourself. Play a bit with the functions `melt` and `dcast` and try `merg`ing with wide and long formats...

Answer (score 1):

It's more manageable if you convert `df` to a long format as well. Then you can just perform a lookup.

You can use the `tidyverse` packages:

```
df %>%
  gather(Id, value, -Person) %>%
  left_join(lfdf, by= c("Person" = "Person", "value" = "type")) %>%
  select(Person, Id, value.y) %>%
  spread(Id, value.y)
```

Comment: if I don't change the long format df into long format, would it better?

Comment: Haven't tried, but since you need to iterate over the columns in `df`, it's easier to have this data in long format, and iterate over the rows. More info would be helpful, like How many columns do you have? How big is the data? Why do you prefer wide format for `lfdf` etc?

Comment: @PeterChung , you can always use `spread` to get everything back in a wide format. Have edited the answer. What's not working for you? Please provide details.

Comment: if both are wide format, would it be easier to do so?

Comment: @PeterChung , to perform a lookup, you need to know the names of the dimensions (rows or columns) on which you need to join them. Since we are joining on `Person` as well as `variables` , it helps to have them along the same dimension.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128032/discussion-between-aramis7d-and-peter-chung).